# Evaluation under integral sign

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and suppose 
$$f(x,y)=\displaystyle\int^x_{x_0} dt\ g(t,y)$$

I wish to calculate $f(x,y_0)$. Can I substitute $y\rightarrow y_0$ in $g(t,y)$ and then integrate, or do I have to integrate first and then replace $y\rightarrow y_0$, or are the two equivalent? If so, is there any result  which formalises this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it both ways, and both will give the same result.

Comment: It is essentially the statement of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, yes?

Comment: No; is just the definition of $f(x,y_0)$. A limit theorem would be needed to compute $\lim_{y\to y_0}f(x,y)$.